# Assign value based on age of occurrence of event in R

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal dataset with participant age and a variable to show the age at which a participant experienced an event (0/1) as follows.

```
id  age  event
 1    0     0
 1    1     0
 1    2     0
 1    3     0
 1    4     0
 1    5     0
 2    0     0
 2    1     1
 2    2     1
 2    3     1
 2    4     1
 2    5     1 
 3    0     0
 3    1     0
 3    2     0
 3    3     1
 3    4     1
 3    5     1
```

Based on whether the event never happened (0) or it happened before the age of 2 yrs (1) or after the age 2 yrs (2), I want to generate a new variable called timing and assign each participant to a group (0,1,2) as follows:

```
id  age  event  timing  
 1    0     0      0
 1    1     0      0
 1    2     0      0
 1    3     0      0
 1    4     0      0
 1    5     0      0
 2    0     0      1
 2    1     1      1
 2    2     1      1
 2    3     1      1
 2    4     1      1
 2    5     1      1
 3    0     0      2
 3    1     0      2
 3    2     0      2
 3    3     1      2
 3    4     1      2
 3    5     1      2
```

I don't have great coding skills and would really appreciate if anyone could assist.

Comment: Please be more clear about what are you asking.

Comment: What if the event happened at exactly 2 years of age?

Comment: If the event never happened, shouldn't the value in `timing` be 0?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610):

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                     age = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
                     event = c(0L,0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,1L)),
                row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

2.A solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% 
              mutate(timing = if_else(age < 2 & event == 1, 1,
                                      if_else(age >= 2 & event == 1, 2, 0))) %>% 
              group_by(id) %>%
              summarize(timing = ifelse(1 %in% timing, 1,
                                        ifelse(2 %in% timing, 2, 0)))
  )
```

This returns:

```
   id age event timing
1   1   0     0      0
2   1   1     0      0
3   1   2     0      0
4   1   3     0      0
5   1   4     0      0
6   1   5     0      0
7   2   0     0      1
8   2   1     1      1
9   2   2     1      1
10  2   3     1      1
11  2   4     1      1
12  2   5     1      1
13  3   0     0      2
14  3   1     0      2
15  3   2     0      2
16  3   3     1      2
17  3   4     1      2
18  3   5     1      2
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I found the solution by @dario very helpful; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you've specified clash with the expected output. So it's hard to know for sure what you need. Intuitively it would make sense that the value in `timing` should always be 0 whatever the age of the participant if the event never happened. If that is correct, then the following nested `ifelse` clauses do create the new variable:

```
df$timing <- ifelse(df$event==0, 0,
                    ifelse(df$event==1 & df$age==1, 1, 2))
```

Result:

```
df
   id age event timing
1   1   0     0      0
2   1   1     0      0
3   1   2     0      0
4   1   3     0      0
5   1   4     0      0
6   1   5     0      0
7   2   0     0      0
8   2   1     1      1
9   2   2     1      2
10  2   3     1      2
11  2   4     1      2
12  2   5     1      2
13  3   0     0      0
14  3   1     0      0
15  3   2     0      0
16  3   3     1      2
17  3   4     1      2
18  3   5     1      2
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Ruehlemann. Thank you for your response. The only issue with your solution is that for the same participant, the code assigns to different groups i.e. 0 or 1 or 2. What I needed is to assign all observations for a participant as either 0 or 1 or 2 based of the first appearance of the event.